# Is it possible to make a backup of my survival world automatically when i exit my game 1.6.4

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

How can i back up my world every 10-15 minutes automatically or auto back it up when i save and exit

I would need this to work with both FTB and updated Minecraft.

Comment: Are you basically asking two independent questions: 1. How do I automatically back-up my worlds? and 2. How do I automate conversion of a Survival world to a Creative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest/simplest way I know of is to simply load your backup and start a LAN game with cheats. That way you have access to commands and can switch your game mode using /gamemode 1 for creative and /gamemode 0 for survival.

One way to have Minecraft automatically backed up when you exit is to use a [symbolic link to Dropbox](http://www.worldofminecraft.com/content/how-automagically-sync-minecraft-worlds-between-multiple-computers-online). This will also allow you to load worlds on a different computer if you want to set it up that way. Perhaps this can help.

Comment: My main question is about how to backup my world when i save and exit really so that it is exactly the same when i load the backup like i do this about 20 times a day, and it gets annoying after a while

Comment: There are several mods that allow for automated backups out there. I used to use one that would backup every 10 minutes, I believe, but there was a glitch that allowed for item duplication so I stopped using it. I haven't tested any others so can't recommend one.
This still isn't a program that will backup when you save and exit though, so I guess that isn't what you're looking for.

Comment: @Flaunting try to create a question with only **one** question... so this type of answer will not occur

Comment: @Michel I DID< Johonn didn't answer my question

Comment: @Flaunting I came upon a method that might work; see if that helps.

Comment: @Johonn So i have found a great mod to do this as there are limited options for 1.6.4 onwards. the following link is for the server tools mod, which can be used in single player, it has an auto backup utility and you can just type /backup to do it manually http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/minecraft-mods/1289612-1-6-4-1-7-2-forge-server-tools